# Logging visits performance wise

Tags: sql, database-design

So I'm developping a website in php, with the framework symfony (not like it matters for the question though).

My website has some kind of articles, pages that will be created.
So I'd like to have counts of visits by day, week, etc... not only for my personal stats but to display on the homepage any article of the day, or something like that.

The way I would do it is : each time someone visit an article, it insert a record in a visit_log table, with the date and the id of the table.
An ON DUPLICATE (or equivalent) would be interesting to perform an update of the count per day instead of an update.

That's pretty simple and working but I can't help but wondering : is it the right way to do ? I'm thinking mostly of performance but of the "well thought" as well. I know the table can get big over time but I guess a cron to clean it regularly would do the trick.

Any thought ? I guess it's a super common thing that people thought of

Comment: Which RDMS are you using the `sql` tag is not a database product.. But most modern RDMS nowdays will handle millions/bilions records just fine when indexes are used..

Comment: @RaymondNijland That goes without saying but my question was general, not focused on a language nor my way to code, nor RDMS.
I'm using MySQL now, but there is a possibility that I go to PostgresSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you facing performance issues with the current implementation?

If you're, then one approach would be: instead of inserting each view directly into the database as it takes place, use an in-memory store to keep a list of pages and their view count `{'Id': 'count'}` for some interval (e.g. 5-10 mins) or till the store reaches a certain size, and after the store reaches its time or size limits, insert the counts into the database.

Another approach is to periodically parse the web-server logs (most web-servers log this information by default), and again do bulk inserts to the database.

Comment: I'm not facing any issues, just wanted to do things a good way. I like your approach with memory, I'll dig into that. Thanks